# Macro to Run Custom Sql Query in Access off Data in Table?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Coworker is completely Access adverse. I can't force him to update a SQL query with a to/from date and customer name. Current query is this:

SELECT   **[all customers]**
FROM  **[information list]**

WHERE 
 **[date]** Between **[start date YYYYMMDD]** and **[end date YYYYMMDD]**
and **[all customers]** = **['specific customer']**

Group By   **[all customers]** *(this prevents duplicate entries or shipping a customer's order between factories counting as a separate order)*

This coworker is so access adverse he wants a wysiwyg and a button to press to overwrite [start date YYYYMMDD] [end date YYYYMMDD] ['specific customer']

I can make a form just fine, but I have no idea how to populate the sql query with form answers. Having him copy and paste these three things into my perfectly good, working query is out of the question, as easy as that answer is.
How would i write a macro that can update this query with those answers replacing the three existing items (the two dates and customer ID)?

Answer (score 0):

you concatenate the textbox values to create the sql query string

```
sql = "SELECT [all customers] FROM [information list]" _
    & "WHERE [date] Between ['" & myForm.Textbox1.Text _
    & "'] and ['" & myForm.Textbox2.Text _
    & "'] and [all customers] = ['" & myForm.Textbox3.Text _
    & "'] Group By [all customers]"
```

adjust the form name and the textbox names to fit your needs